# Where to store strings needed in .NET Core 3.0 application?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I am writing a simple API in .NET Core 3.0. I would like to know the best approach for storing strings that my application need. As an example i have a code snippet:

```
 var user = await _userService.GetUserByIdAsync(id);

 if (user == null)
     return BadRequest(new { Message = "User does not exist" });
```

Everytime that my application has to perform some action on a user, firstly it checks does the user exist. If not a message "User does not exist" is returned. The problem is the code from the snippet appears in a few controller methods (I know, i could create a method, and put the code there, to avoid repeating myself, but it's not a big improvement i think. Maybe i am wrong?). I would not like to have hard-coded text in few places in my code, all these messages should point to some kind of resource which should store strings for my application. I've heard that some developers store that kind of data in a resource files. What are the benefits of this approach? I know that resource files, are also used to get proper text messages for different cultures, but my application supports only one culture. How to create a resource file (shared one, for all cultures), from which i could read text? Is it a good approach, or are there any better solutions?

Comment: A resource is just a file that can be accessed by the application.  Making a resource you would still need to parse the file (or deserialize the data).  So you first have to generate the data.  I like using XML which is easy to parse.  Putting the XML into a resource doesn't allow the data to change once it is delivered.  So if you want to allow users to change the file you could put the file in a known location (or in same folder as executable) so the file can be read by application and changed as needed.

Comment: Is you’d prefer not to use a resources file, a simple solution could be a class with static constant strings with your error text. However, this’ll get quite large if you have lots of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can either put your strings in a resource file or constant file. Resource file would enable you to leverage cultures. So tomorrow, if you decide to support multiple cultures it will be easy for you to handle. There is some out of the box capabilities that .Net core provides for this:-

In your ConfigureService Method.

```
services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

Configure Method.

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(roptions =>
{
    IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
         new CultureInfo("en-US"),
         new CultureInfo("fr"),
    };

   roptions.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
   roptions.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
   roptions.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

});
```

Then the only thing you need to do is to inject the below, anywhere you want to use.

```
IStringLocalizerFactory stringLocalizerFactory.
```

If you see that only one culture suits your need then I think you should wrap things around having const file. I provided the solution for the resource file so that you can probably think about it before you finally pick one approach.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a resource file (shared one, for all cultures)

By default, if you add a new resource file to your project without any suffix (eg. `Resource1.resx`), then it will be a shared one, meaning that obtaining a resource by the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will return that resource.

Resources are in a hierarchy and the the ultimate root is the invariant culture. For example, if the `Thread.CurrentUICulture` property returns the `en-US` culture, then a `ResourceManager` tries to obtain American-English resources in the first place (in our example: the ones from `Resource1.en-US.resx`), if any. If no such resources were found, then it tries to use the neutral English resources (`Resource1.en.resx`), and lastly the invariant (shared) resources.

**Tip:** If your fallback (shared) resources are already in English, then you can make a "shortcut" by adding the `[assembly:NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]` attribute to your assembly. It tells the `ResourceManager` that no hierarchy traversal is needed for the `en-US` culture but it can jump to the invariant resources immediately.

> What are the benefits of this approach? I know that resource files, are also used to get proper text messages for different cultures, but my application supports only one culture.

Your application will able to support more languages without any code change (even if you don't set `Thread.CurrentUICulture`, its default value depends on the current regional settings).

Secondly, it can be beneficial even if you don't plan to add new languages simply because it makes the sources cleaner by separating language-dependent content.

**Tip 2:** If you want to add new languages to your project without recompiling the source code, then you can try the [`HybridResourceManager`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Resources_HybridResourceManager.htm) class, which can use the `.resx` files directly. That way even the users of the already deployed application can add new languages. See also the [`DynamicResourceManager`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Resources_DynamicResourceManager.htm) class, which can dynamically generate the new language files. The linked page contains also an example for how to organize your resources. ([nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/))